# How to debug in VSCode with multiple command line arguments and the difference between launch.json and tasks.json?

Tags: c++, json, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to use the VSCode debugger rather than just plain gdb in the terminal. The particular program I want to debug takes in two command line arguments, and when researching how to take these arguments into account when working with the VSCode debugger, all sources said to place them in the "args" section in launch.json. No matter how I set up the launch.json and tasks.json files, I get a 'executableName not found' error when I run the debug. It shows the path the debugger took to reach the specified executable file, and I have verified that the file does in fact exist in the exact place the debugger's error message said it deosn't.

The executable is the product of a Makefile written by my instructor, which, as far as I am aware, should append all possible arguments to the test-get-sum executable? I am new to makefiles and c++ as a whole, so I have a strong feeling I am very wrong about this.

I believe that the error is of my own ignorance, as I am not sure how to properly configure the VSCode debugging environment for C++, especially when it comes to projects with multiple files and headers that need to be compiled together. There was another question asked a few years back pertaining to the matter of C++ debugging in VSCode, following those instructions and the other solutions also did not work for me. The two error messages I get are along the lines of 'file not found' or 'file format unsupported.' After researching, I am also still unsure of the technical differences between tasks.json and launch.json.

My launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test-find-sum",
            "args": ["dat/row_matrix.txt", "1"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

my tasks.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

the Makefile, for information's sake

```
# use g++ compiler
cc = g++

# add parent to include path and root
path = ..

# compile with C++ 17 standard
flags = -std=c++17
# compile with all warnings
flags += -Wall
# compile with PWD appended to compiler library path
flags += -I $(path)
# compile with debug instrumentation
flags += -g

# compile, assemble, link
link = $(cc) $(flags) -o
# compile, assemble, do not link
compile = $(cc) $(flags) -c

test-find-sum : bin/test-find-sum.o bin/find-sum.o
    $(link) $@ $^


test-find-sum-all : test-find-sum
    @echo 'Running All Tests' \
  && ./test-find-sum dat/row_matrix.txt 0  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/col_matrix.txt 1  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/asc_matrix.txt 2  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/dsc_matrix.txt 3  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/matrix.txt 4  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/matrix.txt 5  \
    && ./test-find-sum dat/large_matrix.txt 6  \
    && echo 'Passed All Tests'


test-find-sum-style : src/find_sum.cpp inc/find_sum.h
    cpplint --root=$(path) $^


test-find-sum-memory : test-find-sum
    @echo MEMORY TEST 0
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/row_matrix.txt 0 > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 0 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 1
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/col_matrix.txt 1  > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 1 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 2
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/asc_matrix.txt 2 > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 2 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 3
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/dsc_matrix.txt 3  > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 3 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 4
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/matrix.txt 4  > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 4 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 5
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/matrix.txt 5 > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 5 PASSED
    @echo MEMORY TEST 6
    valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 \
    ./test-find-sum dat/large_matrix.txt 6 > /dev/null
    @echo MEMORY TEST 6 PASSED
    @echo ALL MEMORY TESTS PASSED


bin/test-find-sum.o : src/test_find_sum.cpp inc/test_find_sum.h \
                        inc/find_sum.h
    $(compile) -o $@ $<


bin/find-sum.o : src/find_sum.cpp inc/find_sum.h
    $(compile) -o $@ $<


clean:
    $(RM) bin/* test-find-sum
```

Comment: Your tasks.json looks wrong for a Makefile. Do you have the makefile tools extension installed in VSCode?

Comment: your build task is not set as a `preLaunchTask` in `launch.json` and your build task does not call `make`, and look at the `cwd` property of `launch.json`